# JSON format and objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, httprequest, nsjsonserialization

My app needs to submit a JSON payload to a server, the server wants the format like so:

```
{
"recipient_emails" :["test@xyz.net", "user@xyz.com"]
}
```

All I can seem to create is this format:

```
{
    "recipient_emails" = ("test@xyz.net", "user@xyz.com");
}
```

What I'm submitting doesn't work, which I can't tell if it's a server issue with our stmp mail server or the format of the JSON i'm submitting.

Here is how I create the json:

```
    //Grab the data (from NSManagedObject)
    NSString *emailData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.submissionRecipients encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Extract all the separate email address
    NSArray *emails = [emailData componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    //If there are some there (which should always be)
    if (emails) {
        NSError *error;

        //Add the array to an NSDictionary with key and convert to JSON
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:emails forKey:@"recipient_emails"] options:0 error:&error];

        //Add json to HTTPRequest
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        //Print out for debug purposes
        NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", dic);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of `NSArray` uses parenthesis - don't worry, if you use `NSJSONSerialization`, the generated JSON will properly contain square brackets.

Comment: So when I convert jsonData back to a NSDictionary and print it out (what's shown in the second print out), the parenthesis are added for convenience?

Comment: @random WYSNWYG ("what you see is NOT what you get"). The description shows the object differently than the JSON. Print out the generated JSON **string** instead and you'll see it's correct.

Comment: I see, looks like its our stmp server. Thank you very much for your help.